# Decompose Hilbert space using bounded linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

if $A$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$, can we decompose $H$ by $
H=\overline{\operatorname{ran} A} \oplus \operatorname{ker} A
$? It seem to me that we need to show that $A$ is actually a closed operator. If that's not right, is there a possible way to decompose $H$ using range and kernal of $A$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $\oplus$?

Comment: Any bounded linear operator is closed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a bounded operator is obviously closed.

Secondly, we have $H=(\ker A)^\perp \oplus \ker A$ and $(\ker A)^\perp=\overline{\text{ran}\, A^*}$. In particular, if $A^*=A$ (self-adjoint) then
$$H=\overline{\text{ran}\, A} \oplus \ker A.$$